# How to persist user session at keycloak running on kubernetes?

Tags: kubernetes, keycloak

After pod restart, all user session data are missing.

But all other data are present after pod restart (ex:- realm, user, realm settings)

keycloak is running with Postgres as persistence storage in a single pod.

[image]

below is the deployment file config:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: idms
  namespace: default
  labels:
    app: idms
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: idms
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: idms
    spec:
      containers:
       - name: postgres
         image: registry.prod.srv.da.nsn-rdnet.net/edge/postgres:12.3-alpine
         imagePullPolicy: "IfNotPresent"
         ports:
           - containerPort: 5432
         lifecycle:
            postStart:
              exec:
                command: ["/bin/bash","-c","sleep 5 && PGPASSWORD=$POSTGRES_PASSWORD psql $POSTGRES_DB -U $POSTGRES_USER -c \'CREATE SCHEMA IF NOT EXISTS keycloak;\'"]  
         envFrom:
           - configMapRef:
               name: postgres-config
       - name: keycloak
         image: quay.io/keycloak/keycloak:10.0.1
         env:
          - name: KEYCLOAK_USER
            value: "XXXXXXX"
          - name: KEYCLOAK_PASSWORD
            value: "XXXXXXX"
          - name: REALM
            value: "XXXXXXX"
          - name: PROXY_ADDRESS_FORWARDING
            value: "true"
          - name: DB_VENDOR
            value: "POSTGRES"
          - name: DB_ADDR
            value: "localhost"
          - name: DB_PORT
            value: "5432"
          - name: DB_DATABASE
            value: "postgresdb"
          - name: DB_USER
            value: "xxxxxxxxx"
          - name: DB_PASSWORD
            value: "xxxxxxxxx"
          - name: DB_SCHEMA
            value: "keycloak"    
          - name: KEYCLOAK_IMPORT
            value: "/opt/jboss/keycloak/startup/elements/realm.json"
         volumeMounts:
           - mountPath: /var/lib/postgresql/data
             name: postgredb 
           - mountPath: /opt/jboss/keycloak/startup/elements
             name: elements 
         ports:
          - name: http
            containerPort: 8080
          - name: https
            containerPort: 8443
         readinessProbe:
            httpGet:
              path: /auth/realms/master
              port: 8080
      volumes:
        - name: elements
          configMap:
            name: keycloak-elements
        - name: postgredb
          persistentVolumeClaim:
            claimName: postgres-pv-claim
```

can you please let me know, any configuration required to persist user session?

Comment: Hi @Siddhanta, I am also facing the same issue, do you find any solution for this, if so can you please share. Also wanted to know what value do we need to give for env variable "REALM"

Comment: @SVD  keycloak uses an embedded Infinispan cache to store user's session information. So, the data saved using Infinispan is not permanent and is not expected to persist in the database. A separate Infinispan cluster is needed to solve this issue. 


refer : https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/server_installation/index.html#cache

by default, keycloak store everything in the master realm. So for application-specific data store you can create a custom realm like "web" and the same name should be passed on that env.

Answer (score 0):

Please take a look at the [existing chart](https://github.com/codecentric/helm-charts/tree/master/charts/keycloak).

On [High Availability and Clustering](https://github.com/codecentric/helm-charts/tree/master/charts/keycloak#high-availability-and-clustering) section, it shows you that you need to set: `CACHE_OWNERS_COUNT` to `2` or higher and `CACHE_OWNERS_AUTH_SESSIONS_COUNT` to `2` or higher.

It's also recommended to use a separate Infinispan cluster if you have a big (more than 1 million from my experience) sessions.